# pass parameter to callback function which is referenced by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to see the value inside callback function which was available when an event was bound. If function is defined when the event is bound then inside the function I can see the value through closure:

```
var number = 777;
$('span').click(function() { 
    alert(number); //alerts 777  - available through closure
});
```

But if the function is defined previously when the 'number' variable was unavailable, the trick won't work. The function number_alerter can't see the 'number' variable if the function is bound to the event in this way:

```
$('span').click(number_alerter);
```

It seems that the only solution is to define the function with the 'number' argument and pass the 'number' varible to the function:

```
//function defined somewhere earlier
function number_alerter(e, number) {    
    alert(number);
}
...
//current scope
var number = 777;
$('span').on('click', function(e) { 
    return number_alerter(e, number);
});
```

My question is whether there is another way to pass this varible to the 'number_alerter' function? Maybe it's also possible through closure?

EDIT:
Here is the real case when the above described might be needed. I have two functions:

```
array_sort(array, compare_function)
compare_values(value1, value2, case_insensitive)
```

The function array_sort passes to compare_values function only two values, while 3rd case insensitive parameter should be also passed when using the function array_sort. The only way I know how to do that is to wrap compare_values function into another function:

```
var my_array = [];
var case_insensitive = true;
var wrapper = function(value1, value2) {
    compare_values(value1, value2, case_insensitive)
}
array_sort(my_array, wrapper);
```

Is there any other way I can do that?

Comment: Why are you doing this.  Step back a little and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.  Is it just trying to save a few characters?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, this is mainly for better understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: Okay.  Just so you know, if this ever comes up in an actual application, it means that your code will confuse most people.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, added real-case example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `number_alerter` to return the callback function, and use a closure. Like this

```
function number_alerter(num) {
    return function(){alert(num);};
}

// different scope
var number = 777;
$('span').on('click', number_alerter(number));
```

See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/4L9Tk/)

Comment: That's certainly a way to do it, thanks! But I would need to alter number_alerter function, which may not always be possible.

Comment: @Maximus: Then you will need your `wrapper`, or some `make_wrapper` helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to be elsewhere. As far as you describe it, the following

```
var number=777;
var alerter=function(){
    alert(number);
};
$("span").click(alerter);
```

works just fine. Cf. the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yU8Mv/)
And, yes, if you need to have access to a defined state (e.g. you define a click-counter for every span) of a variable, it would be done best it with closures.

Edit: Oh, I see

```
$('span').click(
    (function() {
        return number_alerter})());
```

That's not the way to do it. you have to pass the function name at this point.

Comment: You defined your function in the same visiblity scope as the variable 'number', that's why you can see the variable through closure. But I see you've figured out that yourself. I didn't understand your last comment about passing the function name, because that's exactly what I'm doing.