# pass parameter to callback function which referenced by name when passed

Tags: javascript

I have two functions:

```
array_sort(array, compare_function)
compare_values(value1, value2, case_insensitive)
```

The function 'array_sort' uses 'compare_values' function to compare values and passes only two values to it, while the 3rd parameter 'case_insensitive' should be passed when using the function 'array_sort'. The only way I know how to do that is to wrap 'compare_values' function into another function:

```
var my_array = [];
var case_insensitive = true;
var wrapper = function(value1, value2) {
    compare_values(value1, value2, case_insensitive)
}
array_sort(my_array, wrapper);
```

Is there any other way I can do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass parameter to callback function which is referenced by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297518/pass-parameter-to-callback-function-which-is-referenced-by-name)

Comment: @Bergi, no this one includes real-life case, while the one you mentioned was asked for education puproses.

Comment: Well, you edited in your real-life case in that other question. The answer is just the same, so I voted to close as a dupe. Couldn't you apply what you learned there in real life? If you tried and failed this new question is valid, but you had to show us what/how you tried.

Comment: @Bergi, I tried and succeeded :). I'm curious about other ways of doing that.

Comment: We already told you: A `make_wrapper` function that builds the closure for your…

Comment: Can you provdie an example as an answer in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write another function to abstract over the wrapper:

```
function makeWrapper(case_insensitive) {
    return function wrapper(value1, value2) {
        compare_values(value1, value2, case_insensitive)
    };
}

array_sort(my_array, makeWrapper(true));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is another way to do it.